# ISP IP change listener

Tags: ip

I noticed that my IP has changed as reported by "google what is my IP".
I am writing a bash script on my Mac and would like to find a way to run it whenever this IP changes.
The script sends a command to Amazon Web Services.

Is there a way to listen to IP changes and fire such script file?

Comment: Just have it run every hour or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP change is likely at your subscription modem, so what you run on your Mac wouldn't be able to detect the change. You could schedule up a task to run (maybe every hour) that uses an Internet service to check your WAN IP and compare it to the previous run. If the IP changed, then run the script to update AWS.